# Altium: escape from "Top layer (flipped)" view

Tags: altium

While I was using Altium Designer 19, I somehow managed to mirror the PCB across the Y axis, so now I am in view mode "Top layer (flipped)". How can I get back to normal view?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In order to flip, press:

> Ctrl + F

Comment: It's worth adding that this will not work on earlier Altium versions. I don't know about version 18, but for versions before 17, you need to do `Alt-V`, `B`, or menu item "View->Flip Board".

Comment: I've typically just used `V`, `B` (Altium doesn't require "alt" to be pressed to access the view menu.) Thanks for the answer, it provides another method I didn't know about.